# Selenium Web Scraping (element not interactable)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrap a website with navigating the different pages.

I tried this code on another website that works for scrapping. I have now trying to scrap another website and failed.

It shows that "*selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable*"

And like, *".areaUnitPrice.separation''* is unable to scrap the text

But I can't find the issue.. can anyone help to solve this.. Many thanks!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.28hse.com/buy/residential/a1")
for i in range(3):
    all_cells = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item.property_item")

    for cell in all_cells:
        names = cell.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".areaUnitPrice.separation")

        if len(names) > 0:
            print(names[0].text)
        else:
            print("--- no name ---")

    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination_hi:nth-of-type(2)")
    next_btn.click()
    try:
        print(f"Done page {i+1}")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-brief-wrapper"))
        )
    except:
        print("Wait failed")
```

Comment: What is the expected output? I mean if you print `names[0]` what should it display.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations:

--> `.areaUnitPrice.separation` does not work as `.separation` is inside the `.areaUnitPrice`. It should be `.areaUnitPrice .separation` - this works.

--> `.separation` has a blank text, but I suppose you are looking for the price instead.

The below workaround fetched result for me. Please check:

```
driver.get("https://www.28hse.com/buy/residential/a1")
for i in range(3):
    all_cells = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item.property_item")
    for cell in all_cells:
        names = cell.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.areaUnitPrice')
        if len(names)>0:
            name = [i.text for i in names]
            last_item = name[-1]
            print(last_item)
            # if you only want the price to be displayed, use below 3 lines:
            # split_items = last_item.split('@')
            # price = split_items[-1]
            # print(price)
            
        else:
            print('--- no name ----')
```

Output:

```
建築面積: 688 呎 @17,151 元
實用面積: 490 呎 @24,082 元
實用面積: 476 呎 @18,887 元
建築面積: 877 呎 @11,403 元
實用面積: 597 呎 @16,750 元
建築面積: 902 呎 @13,249 元
實用面積: 710 呎 @16,832 元
```

Note: I didn't include the next page button. You may add your code to this, if this solution works for you.